# Child processes running in random order and before parent finishes loop?

Tags: c

I created a for loop in C that is responsible for creating a given amount of processes. There is a section in the for loop (pid > 0) for the parent, and a section for the child (pid == 0). The wait() function call is after the loop finishes, but I am having a problem where some of the child processes start executing their fprintf statements while the parent is still running the for loop. How can I make sure all of the children do NOT start running until the parent has gone through the for loop and finished all fprintf statements in order?

````
> ./a.out 5 process 1
*[EXPECTED]*
Process 0 creating process 1...
Process 0 creating process 2...
Process 0 creating process 3...
Process 0 creating process 4...
Process 0 creating process 5...
Process 1 beginning...
*(SLEEP RANDOM AMOUNT OF TIME)*
Process 1 ending...
Process 2 beginning...
*(SLEEP RANDOM AMOUNT OF TIME)*
Process 2 ending...
Process 3 beginning...
*(SLEEP RANDOM AMOUNT OF TIME)*
Process 3 ending...
Process 4 beginning...
*(SLEEP RANDOM AMOUNT OF TIME)*
Process 4 ending...
Process 5 beginning...
*(SLEEP RANDOM AMOUNT OF TIME)*
Process 5 ending...```

```*[ACTUAL RESULT]*
Process 0 creating process 1...
Process 1 beginning...
Process 0 creating process 2...
Process 2 beginning...
Process 0 creating process 3...
Process 0 creating process 4...
Process 0 creating process 5...
Process 5 beginning...
Process 3 beginning...
Process 4 beginning...
*(SLEEP RANDOM AMOUNT OF TIME)*
Process 1 ending...
Process 2 ending...
Process 5 ending...
Process 3 ending...
Process 4 ending...`
````

The output is never not the same, and the child processes often begin in a random order in between each parent process loop iteration.

Here is my code:
main.c:

```
/*
 * Write a program that takes three arguments:
 * the number of “things” (between 1 and 256),
 * a word: either “thread” or “process, and
 * a “pattern number” (1-2 only).
 */
#include "functions.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// USE STDERR FOR PRINTING
// fprintf(stderr, "This is process %d \n", getpid());

// extern set_pattern

typedef struct {
  int number;
  pid_t pid;
} process;

typedef struct {
  int number;
  pthread_t tid;
} thread;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);

  // Check for correct amount of paramters
  if (argc != 4) {
    help_and_exit(argv[0]);
  }
  // Parse parameters and check for errors

  // Set size
  int size;
  set_size(argv, &size);

  // Set type (thread or process)
  exec_t type;
  set_choice(argv, &type);

  // Set pattern
  int pattern;
  set_pattern(argv, &pattern);

  // printf("Size is %d, choice is %d, and pattern is %d\n", size, type,
  // pattern);

  if (pattern == 1) {
    if (type == Process) {
      // process processes[size];
      pid_t alpha_process = getpid();
      int process_number = 0;

      pid_t pids[size];
      int n = size;
      int flag = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
          perror("fork");
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Process %d beginning...\n", i + 1);
          sleep(rand() % 5);
          fflush(stdout);
          fprintf(stderr, "Process %d ending...\n", i + 1);
          exit(0);
        } else if (pids[i] > 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Process %d creating process %d...\n", i - i, i + 1);
        }
      }

      int counter = 0;
      while (counter < n) {
        wait(NULL);
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

functions.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef enum { Thread, Process } exec_t;

void help_and_exit(char *name) {
  fprintf(stderr,
          "usage: %s <number of things> {thread | process} <pattern number>\n",
          name);
  exit(-1);
}

void set_size(char *argv[], int *size) {
  if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", size) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "First parameter must be an integer. Recieved: '%s'\n",
            argv[1]);
    help_and_exit(argv[0]);
  }
  if (*size > 256 || *size < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Number of things must be between 1-256!\n");
    help_and_exit(argv[0]);
  }
}

void set_choice(char *argv[], exec_t *type) {
  char choice[8];
  if (sscanf(argv[2], "%s", choice) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Second parameter must be a string. Recieved: '%s'\n",
            argv[2]);
    help_and_exit(argv[0]);
  }
  if (strcmp(choice, "thread") != 0 && strcmp(choice, "process") != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Second parameter must be either 'thread' or 'process'\n");
    help_and_exit(argv[0]);
  } else if (strcmp(choice, "thread") == 0) {
    *type = Thread;
  } else {
    *type = Process;
  }
}
void set_pattern(char *argv[], int *pattern) {
  if (sscanf(argv[3], "%d", pattern) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Third parameter must be an integer. Recieved: '%s'\n",
            argv[3]);
    help_and_exit(argv[0]);
  }
  if (*pattern != 1 && *pattern != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Pattern number must be either 1 or 2!\n");
    help_and_exit(argv[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You must synchronize the parent process and the children using some interprocess communication mechanisms. If you use Linux/macOS, a counting semaphore (`man semget`) is a plausible solution.

Comment: @DYZ, just added it.

Comment: @DYZ, I know how to use interprocess communication, but how would it still just not run during the for loop while the parent is running? Sorry I may need you to spell it out for me.

Comment: Create an initially closed semaphore in the parent. Make each child wait on it. Open the semaphore in the parent after the loop.

Comment: Alternatively, put each child on `pause()` and let the parent wake them up after the loop by sending a signal (do not forget to have the signal handlers in the children).

Comment: @DYZ, thank you so much, I just fixed it with the pause & signal combo and now it is working perfectly as intended. Bless you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put each child on pause() and have the parent wake them up after the loop by sending a signal. (Credit to DYZ for the answer)

```
#include "functions.c"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//snip-snip...

int cont;

void handleContinueSignal(int sig) { cont = 1; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // snip-snip...

  if (pattern == 1) {
    if (type == Process) {

    // snip-snip...

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
          perror("fork");
        } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
          signal(SIGCONT, handleContinueSignal);
          pause();
          fprintf(stderr, "Process %d beginning...\n", i + 1);
          sleep(rand() % 5);
          fflush(stdout);
          fprintf(stderr, "Process %d ending...\n", i + 1);
          exit(0);
        } else if (pids[i] > 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Process %d creating process %d...\n", i - i, i + 1);
        }
      }

      int counter = 0;
      while (counter < n) {
        kill(pids[counter], SIGCONT);
        wait(NULL);
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```